# Django REST Framework group by in nested model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django REST Framework.

I have a nested model for saving orders of a restaurant. When I send a GET request I get the following response:

```json
[
  {
    "menu": {
      "id": 1,
      "food_name": "food1"
    },
    "user": {
      "id": 49,
      "username": "A"
    }
  },
  {
    "menu": {
      "id": 1,
      "food_name": "food1"
    },
    "user": {
      "id": 63,
      "username": "B"
    }
  }
]
```

But I want to group users with the same menu like this:

```json
[
  {
    "menu": {
      "id": 1,
      "food_name": "food1",
      "users": {
        "1": {
          "id": 49,
          "username": "A"
        },
        "2": {
          "id": 63,
          "username": "B"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Here is my code:

**models.py**

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```py
class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
```

**serilizers.py**

```py
class OrderSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    menu = MenuSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'menu']
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your output suggests that you are working with menus, I suggest you create a separate viewset that works with menus and returns the expected output you want here.

Doing the expected results in the order viewset is possible, but is tricky to optimise using `select_related` and `prefetch_related`. But if you really want this in your order viewset, then you can do this with:

```
class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ['id', 'food_name', 'users']

    def get_users(self, obj):
        users = User.objects.filter(pk__in=obj.order_set.all().values('user'))
        return UserSerializer(users, many=True).data


class OrderSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    menu = MenuSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id', 'menu']
```

You also need to change the queryset of the view if you want distinct results, otherwise you will get duplicates:

```
class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Order.objects.all().distinct('menu')
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
```

Do note that this is not optimised, and each row in your order table will require hitting the database just to get the users through menu. `distinct('menu')` also only works on PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was helpful in showing my desired result. but still there is a little problem, in "duplication" as  you said. since i use sqlite3, it doesn't support distinct ('menu')

Comment: That's a little tricky. Do you use sqlite in production as well? Try to use `Order.objects.values('menu').distinct()`

Comment: I did this before, but got another error. Something like this: "'int' object has no attribute 'food_name'."

Comment: Yes sorry cancel that. You can't use `menu` in `values` because it will turn it into an int.

Comment: So do you think there is no way to get distinct value in sqlite? should i change my DB?

Comment: If you want to release this publicly, yes might as well. I would suggest postgres

Comment: Of course. But I emphasis that this method only should work in PostgreSQL, Not in SQLite and MySQL; Because `distinct('menu')` only supported in on PostgreSQL.

And in fact, using `MenuSerializer` (instead of `OrderSerializer`), I got almost what I wanted.

Comment: Yep I've added that

Answer (score 0):

You can nest User into Menu if you want to group by menu

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    menu = MenuSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id', 'menu']


class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ['id', 'user']
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i get the following error:    "TypeError at /orders,
'Menu' object is not iterable"

Comment: In that case you need to remove many=True from `menu = MenuSerializer(many=True)`. Why don’t you show your Menu model also?

Comment: Thanks, the other answer was almost helpful.